# mysqli_free_result() on result set returned from function

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a function doing a simple query and returning the result set:

```
function getAdmins($dbcon) {

    $qry  = "SELECT * ";
    $qry .= "FROM admins ";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $qry);
    if (!$result) die("Admin query failed");

    return $result;

}
```

I want to understand what exactly is happening when I then do this:

```
$admin_result = getAdmins($dbcon);
// do stuff with $admin_result
mysqli_free_result($admin_result);
```

Am I returning a reference from `getAdmins()` to the `$result` variable I created there and freeing that, or am I creating a copy of `$result` in `$admin_result` and the original `$result` gets freed when the function returns? And then do I also need to free `$admin_result` like I am doing? I just want to know what is happening under the hood with this process. I am used to C where there would be some issues with this if it were memory management.

Answer (score 1):

you can use spl_object_hash to detect whether $admin_result and $result is the same object.

in getAdmins function:

```
echo 'hash of $result is '. spl_object_hash($result) . '<br/>';
return $result;
```

and then

```
$admin_result = getAdmins($dbcon);
echo 'hash of $admin_result is '. spl_object_hash($admin_result) . '<br/>';
```

if two hash are the same , that means they are the same object